# Как получать текущее CSS значение элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

У меня есть элемент который будет изменять своё свойство scale **динамически**, и мне надо получать значение scale каждый раз, как оно изменяется, желательно без каких либо библиотек.

Я знаю, что можно получить значение css свойства через getComputedStyle(), но если я не ошибаюсь оно получает его всего один раз, а мне надо, чтоб каждый раз, как значение изменялось.

Comment: А какую задачу это должно решить? И «динамически» - это какая-то бесконечная анимация или при изменении размера окна?

Comment: При скролле, элемент уменьшается и увеличивается, и при достижение определенного размера элемент должен пропадать

Comment: Если меняется при скролле, значит уже прикручен JS. Надо бы найти ту функцию, которая меняет scale, немного изменить, чтобы и меняла, и заодно проверяла новый размер. При необходимости - скрывала...

Comment: Если есть возможость, лучше менять свойство scale через js и соответственно там же менять переменную, а с неё уже брать значение.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось вот так, на примере этой программы видно изменение значения sacle, его получение после изменение и применение полученного значения

```js
window.onload = function(){
   var cube = document.getElementById("cube")
   
   setInterval(CubeTransform,500)
   var i = 0;
   var mn = 0.5;
   function CubeTransform(){
   i = i + mn;
   cube.style = "transform: scale("+i+");";
   if(i == 5||i == 0){mn = mn*-1}
   cube.innerHTML = cube.style.transform;// Получаем sacle куба в любой момент
   
   }

}
```

```css
  #cube {
    
    
    margin: 20%;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(235, 120, 235);
    height: 30px;
    
    }
    body {
    margin: 0; 
    }
```

```html
    <div id="cube" style="transform: scale(1)">
        
      </div>
```